# R: function to detect time-invariant variables

Tags: r, dataframe, function, group-by

Suppose we have the following dataset:

```
Lines <- "id time sex Age
1  1       male   90
1  2       male   91
1  3       male   92
2  1       female  87
2  2       female  88
2  3       female  89
3  1       male  50
3  2       male  51
3  3       male  52
4  1       female  54
4  2       female  55
4  3       female  56"

dat <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

I would like to create a function that scans all columns in the dataset except id and time and retrieves a string mentioning which variables are not time-invariant (change for every time period). In this example, it would be `Age`.

Comment: Presumably this is within id?  And what about a variable that evolves, within id as, say 1, 2, 1?  ie, in which the number of distinct values is not equal to the number of time periods?  How do you wish to handle missing values: do they "count" or should they be ignored?

Comment: Is this equivalent to compute the variance (or sd) grouped by time? Then 'aggregate()' with 'FUN=sd' and 'by=list(dat$time)' should do the trick: just look where sd is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr` here is an option -

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(across(-time, ~all(. != lag(.), na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  select(where(~is.logical(.) && all(.))) %>%
  names

#[1] "Age"
```

Within each `id` except `time` column return `TRUE` if the current value is different than the previous value for all the values. We can return the column name where all the values are `TRUE` for every `id`.